# How do I find a delete rows that have URLs with trailing slashes in Excel?

Tags: excel

How would I go about deleting rows that have more than 3 slashes? For example;

http://www.example.com/

http://www.example.com/blahblah/i-want-this-one-deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Your data starts From `A1` cell

Place this formula on `B1` cell and drag this down to fill the series.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))
```

This will give you the count of slashes in the Reference cell (here in this example cell `A1`)

You can now filter out the count more than 3 and delete the rows.

Comment: Wow, very simple solution. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help! If it helped mark this question as answered by accepting the answer so it doesn't reflect in the 'Unanswered' category.